# Include a string with spaces

Tags: texworks

So, I know that questions about how to deal with spaces have been asked a thousand times. But this problem seems unique

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1]{"Multi page.pdf"}
\end{document}
```

running this in TeXworks gives me the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .pdf".
```

it's like LaTeX accepted the opening quote but got confused by the last one thinking that it is part of the extension. It works if I just rename Multi page.pdf to MultiPage.pdf, but I want a general solution for handling spaces. Any help with this one? Including file names with spaces should be such an elementary thing...

Comment: The latest LaTeX kernel update will load this with or without the quotes: can you give more details of your set up? In particular, can you tell us what LaTeX version is listed in your `.log`?

Comment: @JosephWright it seems that no log file was generated. I'm running the .tex file from my desktop and there is not .log file on my desktop. However, the console output at the bottom of TeXworks says "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)"

Comment: So it's impossible to have filenames with spaces in them? That seems bizarre.

Comment: No, quite the opposite: recent changes have been focussed on making sure as far as possible spaces _are_ supported. As I said earlier, we need to know your LaTeX version: it's going to look like `LaTeX 2e <YYYY-MM-DD>`

Comment: my version was 2017. I updated it and now the code in my OP works. Thanks